# How to find Average Rating and get all the Review to the corresponding Product

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

`I have refernced user and product to reviewSchema, I need to find the average rating and get all reviews for corresponding productId below is the Schame for my reviewSchema`
I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId `the above code is returning the Empty I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productIdI need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId`
the above code is returning the Empty
I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productIdI need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId `the above code is returning the Empty I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productIdI need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId`
the above code is returning the Empty
I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    productId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Product",
    },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
    comment: { type: String, required: true },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
    },
    like: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    unlike: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Review", reviewSchema);
```

`Above is the Schame for Review`

`In the below code is Returning all the reviews corresponding to the ProductId`

```
exports.getAllReviewsForProduct = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const { productId } = req.params;
  console.log("Product Id", productId);
  const allReviews = await Review.find({ productId }).populate("user");

 res.send(allReviews);
});
```

`But when i use the aggerate method to fetch all review it returning Empty But when i use the aggerate method to fetch all review it returning Empty`

````
const avgReview = await Review.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        productId: "productId",
      },
    },
])
```

`I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId`
the above code is returning the Empty
 I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId`
the above code is returning the Empty
 I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId`
the above code is returning the Empty
 I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId`
the above code is returning the Empty
 I need Average rating and all the reviews(comments) for corrersponding productId`
````

Answer (score 0):

Populate feature in aggregate...please refer.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/